# Child form calling function on parent in .NET c++

Tags: c++, .net, winforms, c++-cli

I'm having an application with 2 winforms: Form1.h and TrackEdit.h. They're both in the same namespace ("ParkCleanUp2").

From within Form1 I call this code:

```
ParkCleanUp2::TrackEdit^ te;
```

Where it gives me these errors:

```
Error   24  error C2039: 'TrackEdit' : is not a member of 'ParkCleanUp2' (TrackEdit.cpp)    c:\users\-joey\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\park cleanup 2\park cleanup 2\Form1.h  2332
Error   25  error C2065: 'TrackEdit' : undeclared identifier (TrackEdit.cpp)    c:\users\-joey\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\park cleanup 2\park cleanup 2\Form1.h  2332
Error   26  error C2065: 'te' : undeclared identifier (TrackEdit.cpp)   c:\users\-joey\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\park cleanup 2\park cleanup 2\Form1.h  2332
```

Though, if I go to TrackEdit.h it show me:

```
namespace ParkCleanUp2 {
 //Some namespae includes
     public ref class TrackEdit : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
```

So I'm wondering why it's giving me the error "*'TrackEdit' : is not a member of 'ParkCleanUp2'*" and why it's looking into the TrackEdit.cpp file, while I included the .h file.
What I found to be weird, and maybe important to mention, is that when I comment the `#include "Form1.h` line in TrackEdit.h it just works perfect, but in TrackEdit.h I than can't call Form1's functions (like selected an item in a listbox) which I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Can you show us your code then?

Comment: The only thing I can guess is that you've used `ParkCleanUp2.TrackEdit` instead of `ParkCleanup2::TrackEdit`, is that true?

Comment: @AntonieBlom This is the code I currently use to run the form:
ParkCleanUp2::TrackEdit^ te = gcnew ParkCleanUp2::TrackEdit(TrackUIDs[track_list->SelectedIndex]);
te->ShowDialog();

Though, this one is giving me the "'TrackEdit' : is not a member of 'ParkCleanUp2'" error, if I remove the "ParkCleanUp2::" namespace prefix that error is gone, but the other ones are still there.

So if I use this code:
TrackEdit^ te = gcnew TrackEdit(TrackUIDs[track_list->SelectedIndex]);
te->ShowDialog();

The first error is fixed, but the other ones are still there.

Comment: I would suggest editing your question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have both Form1.h and TrackEdit.h each `#include`-ing the other. Instead, have a forward declaration, and only include Form1.h from TrackEdit.**cpp**, and vise-versa.

The double-include doesn't work because you've got both classes referencing the other. Each class needs to know about the other in order to define itself. Since all you have is the full class definition, you've got a circular definition. Instead, the forward declaration provides just enough for the compiler to know "OK, there's a class with that name, and that's all I know about it", and the circular dependency is resolved.

(Also: When you edited the question, you removed the most important sentence: "so basically Form1.h includes TrackEdit.h, which includes Form1.h again". That pattern is very rarely correct. If you see yourself doing that, provide more forward declarations instead.)

Something like this:

Form1.h:

```
namespace ParkCleanUp2 {
    ref class TrackEdit;

    public ref class Form1 {
        TrackEdit^ track;
    };
}
```

TrackEdit.h:

```
namespace ParkCleanUp2 {
    ref class Form1;

    public ref class TrackEdit {
        Form1^ parentForm;
    };
}
```

Form1.cpp and TrackEdit.cpp:

```
#include "Form1.h"
#include "TrackEdit.h"
```

Comment: This seems to work, however I got one new error though when I used those forward references and this code:
`ParkCleanUp2::TrackEdit^ tr = gcnew ParkCleanUp2::TrackEdit();`

The error:
`Error 13 error C2512: 'ParkCleanUp2::TrackEdit' : no appropriate default constructor available c:\users\-joey\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\park cleanup 2\park cleanup 2\Form1.h 2332`

Note that `TrackEdit^ tr;` doesn't give any errors. The constructor is as below:

`public ref class TrackEdit : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
 {
 public:
  TrackEdit(void)
  {
   InitializeComponent();
  }`

Comment: In the header file, there's no class definition available, just the forward declaration, so there's no constructors, methods, properties, anything. Move that line into the cpp file, where the full class definition is available.

Comment: Somehow this doesn't seem to be the right way too. When I created a new forms app to try this code exactly as you say it doesn't work as it won't compile the "public ref class Form1" with the "public" prefix ('public' can only be used in definitions, it says). It gives a possibly usefull error though: "A top level visibility specifier requires a type definition". Am I somehow doing it wrong?

Comment: My mistake, the forward declaration shouldn't include the word `public`. See edit.

Comment: Now it works as long as I don't refer to code of another form. When in Form1.h I add this rule at a button evenhandler: `TrackEdit^ te;` it just works/compiles, but as soon as I change it to this: `TrackEdit^ te = gcnew TrackEdit();` it doesn't compile anymore giving the error: `ParkCleanUp2::TrackEdit no appropriate default constructor available` while this constructor normally works well.

Comment: Do the `gcnew TrackEdit()` in Form1.cpp, and it'll work fine.

Comment: This indeed fixed the problem. I basically moved the button click handler to the .cpp file and that fixed the problem!